# How to create dummy RPM which pretends to provide Python modules?

Tags: python, rpm, packaging, rpm-spec, python-packaging

I need to create a dummy RPM which appears to install some Python modules in site-packages to resolve an RPM dependency issue.

The real modules will be installed using PIP inside of a Python Virtual Environment, but in order for the system to work the modules which are imported need to be provided in the global site packages, so that needs to be faked.

The imports look as follows (example): `from pear.apple.peach import Fruit`

When performing an RPM Build on the package that has these imports it fails on dependency generation, so I need an RPM in the local repo to pretend to provide these so the dependency generation passes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by replicating every import with an empty file, and using empty `__init__.py` files at every folder level.

For example, to resolve `from pear.apple.peach import Fruit`, I would have needed to install the following file tree in site-packages:

```
-> pear
  -> __init__.py
  -> apple
    -> peach.py
```

The relevant lines of the spec file for the dummy rpm:

```
...
source:FruitDummy.tar.gz    
...
% install
mkdir -p $RPM_BUILD_ROOT%{python_sitelib}/pear/apple/

install __init__.py $RPM_BUILD_ROOT%{python_sitelib}/pear/
install peach.py $RPM_BUILD_ROOT%{python_sitelib}/pear/apple/
...
%files
%defattr(-,root,root,-)
%{python_sitelib}/pear/__init__.py*
%{python_sitelib}/pear/apple/peach.py*
...
```

`__init__.py` and `peach.py` were stored in the `FruitDummy.tar.gz` that was used to build the RPM.

Answer (score 1):

The approach you are proposing in the question doesn't make much sense to me, either you create rpm packages with python modules you need for other system rpm packages (packages you plan to create or install) or you just use virtual env and then you don't need to care much about what you have in system site packages, as long as you have particular version of python itself installed. While you can make system site packages visible in particular virtual env (for example, when you have lxml module among dependencies, you can install it from rpm package and then make a virtual env to have access to system site packages so that you don't need to install it again in virtualenv), having particular module provided in dummy rpm package would break it so this doesn't make sense as well.

In other words, having something installed in virtual env and then expect to make system python module installed via rpm package to depend on something from that virtual env is not going to work (imho).

So I suggest to do one of:

- Build the rpm packages of modules you need to have installed for other packages to work. As long as you have some experience with rpmbuild, it should not be that hard, you can use [pyp2rpm](https://github.com/fedora-python/pyp2rpm) tool to create initial specfile which you would need to tweak a bit. But this also depends on how many of the packages you need to build and how often do you plan to update them (as it would mean to update the specfile and rebuild).
- Use virtual env only, either with access to system site packages or not. This way, you install both dependencies and application into virtual env and you don't need to deal with rpm packages at all (as long as you install python and virtualenv from rpm packages).

Which way would make more sense in you case depends heavily on what are you trying to do (how do you plan to maintain the python modules, on how many machines do you plan to install it, if you plan to install it yourself or provide it for others to install it themselves and so on ...).

Comment: I'm working within a build system that automatically generates dependencies for all Python files, and fails if the dependencies cannot be met with the RPMs from either (1) other source packages in the project or (2) from a local prebuilt RPM cache. The constraint that my question is based on is not a usual one, but it is the one I'm facing.